# firebase functions Build failed: npm ERR! code EBADPLATFORM

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

when i try to deploy a functions to firebase cloud functions i get the next error:

```
functions: updating Node.js 16 function MGSERVER(us-central1)...
Build failed: npm ERR! code EBADPLATFORM
npm ERR! notsup Unsupported platform for @next/swc-darwin-arm64@13.3.0: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"arm64"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm ERR! notsup Valid OS:    darwin
npm ERR! notsup Valid Arch:  arm64
npm ERR! notsup Actual OS:   linux
npm ERR! notsup Actual Arch: x64

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /www-data-home/.npm/_logs/2023-04-19T14_09_08_794Z-debug-0.log; Error ID: beaf8772

Functions deploy had errors with the following functions:
        MGSERVER(us-central1)
i  functions: cleaning up build files...

Error: There was an error deploying functions
```

All the things i try will fail, even when try do downgrade firebase-tools to 11.0.0  or any other version with:

```
npm install -g firebase-tools@11.0.0
```

After I run `firebase tools --version` it will say `11.18.0`

my node version is: `16.20.0`

does any one has a solution because now i can't update any functions anymore..

Comment: Why are you including/using `swc-darwin-arm64`? Are you testing locally on macOS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a file at the root of your project named `.babelrc` and add the following contents:

```json
{
  "presets": [
    "next/babel"
  ]
}
```

This will instruct it to skip using the Rust-based compiler as discussed at [failed-loading-swc](https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/failed-loading-swc). There are other options discussed there as well, such as removing your `package-lock.json` and your `node_modules` directory and reinstalling swc with the `--optional` flag:

```bash
npm install --save next@^13.3.0 --include=optional
```

But this is the nuclear option and not guaranteed to work on external build systems like the Cloud Build environment.